# How to rewrite ON clause to avoid using OR

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlperformance

I have a very inefficient query, due to using an `OR` as part of the `ON` statement in a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT Meetings.SomeFields, Organisations.SomeFields,
FROM Meetings
     LEFT JOIN Users
          ON (Meetings.AdministratorID = Users.UserID
              OR Meetings.ChairpersonID = Users.UserID)
     LEFT JOIN Organisations
          ON Organisations.OrganisationID = Users.OrganisationID;
```

*(Note: This is a slight simplification to demonstrate the problem.  In practice, this is a complex query with about 20 tables, but I have reduced the performance issue down to this small subset of the query.)*

This attempts to implement the following logic for joining to an organisation:  If there is a chairperson, then the chairperson's organisation should be used.  Otherwise, the administrator's organisation should be used.  Either or both of these fields will be filled in, and a subsequent WHERE clause ensures that no extraneous records (e.g. where both are filled in) are included in the outupt.

Using `EXPLAIN` I can see that the `OR` operator means that indexes can't be used and all row combinations need to be checked individually.  With ~100k Meeting records and ~70k User records, this has a huge query performance issue as this means ~7 billion combinations need to be checked.

Removing the `OR Meetings.ChairpersonID = Users.UserID` part of the expression results in an instant result as the query can use the indexes properly, but obviously doesn't give the result we need.

**Can anyone suggest a way of rewriting this query to avoid the performance issues?**

I am using MySQL 5.

Comment: What are you trying to count?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: Don't simplify too much, put a few select list _columns_ back.

Comment: Nothing really - the count was just to simplify the example.  The field list contains fields that are needed for the surrounding join (not included).

Comment: @jarlh - Will do.  Bear with...

Comment: "If... otherwise..." is not OR, it's implication. Perhaps you need `COALESCE(ChairpersonID, AdministratorID) = UserID`?

Comment: @jarlh I have updated the example to give some more context.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic - Hmmm.... that looks promising.  Do you want to write that up as an answer?

Comment: @HappyDog Done, please give it a go!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If there is a chairperson, then the chairperson's organisation should be used. Otherwise, the administrator's organisation should be used.

"If... otherwise..." is not OR, it's implication, which you can compactly express via COALESCE:

```
SELECT Meetings.SomeFields, Organisations.SomeFields,
FROM Meetings
     LEFT JOIN Users
          ON COALESCE(Meetings.ChairpersonID, Meetings.AdministratorID) = Users.UserID
     LEFT JOIN Organisations
          ON Organisations.OrganisationID = Users.OrganisationID;
```

This way, for each `Meetings` row, the corresponding `Users` row can be found by seeking the `Users` PK.

---

One more thing... if `ChairpersonID` and `AdministratorID` cannot *both* be NULL, then you can inner-join to `Users`.

Comment: Brilliant - this solves the performance issues.  It also means we no longer need to worry about filtering unwanted rows from the results in cases where both users match but the organisation is different.  Unfortunately, it is possible for both fields to be NULL so we can't switch to an INNER JOIN, but the LEFT JOIN doesn't seem to cause any performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `exists`:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Meetings m
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Users u
              WHERE u.UserID = m.AdministratorID
             ) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM Users u
              WHERE u.UserID = m.ChairpersonID
             );
```

This can take advantage of the index on `Users(UserId)` -- which is there automatically if `UserId` is the primary key.

Note:  I think this does what you want by counting *meetings*.  your version counts users.  So if the chair and administrator are both in `Users` for a given meeting, then that counts as 2 users rather than 1 meeting.

Comment: I have updated the question to remove the ```COUNT()``` as this was muddying the waters.  This was just a simplification to reduce the query to minimum parts, but it turns out to be a bit misleading.  Hopefully the updated example should make things a bit clearer.